# Can I setup CVSROOT with remote access?

Tags: repository, cvs, remote-access

I created a cvs repository in my school network account, I would love to have the access to it using my local machines at home. I tried, at local, setting CVSROOT variable to be "myUserID@schoolServer:/u/myUserId/cs/csvroot", but it complains, about the $CVSROOT value, when I tried to use it. I also tried "cvs -d " option, but still not working. What can I do?
thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give us the actual error messages that it gives you; they may contain useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `CVS_RSH` to `ssh` (or whatever you use to access schoolServer.).